# How to change aspect ratio of preview/capture in camera2?

Tags: android, resolution, android-camera2, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to change the aspect ratio in camera2 without success. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

I've tried to change the resolution in ImageReader but this doesn't change the aspect ratio. The picture is still took in 4:3.

```
ImageReader.newInstance(
  500,
  500,
  ImageFormat.JPEG,
  1)
```

And the preview but it is disorted.

```
surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(500, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only certain resolutions and aspect ratios are directly supported by the camera device.

You can get that list for a given format or destination object via [StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap?hl=en#getOutputSizes(int)), which you can get from [CameraCharacteristics.get(SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics?hl=en#SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)

Generally that only includes 4:3 and 16:9 aspect ratios, though some devices do support some square sizes. If you want to guarantee square output, you need to do that cropping yourself.